# script to copy, install and execute on multiple hosts

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I am trying to copy few files into multiple hosts, install/configure those on each with running specific commands depending on OS type. The IP addresses for each host are read from host.txt file.

It appears when I run the script, it does not execute on the remote hosts. Can someone help identify the issues with this script? Sorry for this basic one, I am quite new into shell scripting.

```
#!/bin/bash


export AGENT=agent-x86-64-linux-5.8.1.tar.gz
export AGENT_PROPERTIES_NONDMZ=agent.properties.nondmz
export agent_INIT=agent.sh

echo "####Installing hqagent####"

while read host; do
  scp $AGENT $AGENT_PROPERTIES_NONDMZ $agent_INIT root@$host:/opt
  if ssh -n root@$host '[ "$(awk "/CentOS/{print}" /etc/*release)" ] '
  then
    cd /opt
    tar -xvzf $AGENT
    mv -f /opt/agent.properties.nondmz /opt/agent-5.8.1/conf/agent.properties
    mkdir /opt/hqagent/
    ln -s /opt/agent-5.8.1/ /opt/hqagent/agent-current
    useradd hqagent
    groupadd hqagent
    chown -R hqagent:hqagent /opt/hqagent /opt/agent-5.8.1/
    cd /etc/init.d
    chmod 755 hqagent.sh
    chkconfig --add hqagent.sh
    su - hqagent
    /opt/agent-5.8.1/bin/hq-agent.sh start
  else
    cd /opt
    tar -xvzf $AGENT
    mv -f /opt/agent.properties.nondmz /opt/agent-5.8.1/conf/agent.properties
    rm -rf /opt/hqagent.sh
    mkdir /opt/hqagent/
    ln -s /opt/agent-5.8.1/ /opt/hqagent/agent-current
    useradd hqagent
    groupadd hqagent
    chown -R hqagent:hqagent /opt/hqagent /opt/agent-5.8.1
    cd /etc/init.d
    ln -s /opt/hqagent/agent-current/bin/hq-agent.sh hqagent.sh
    cd /etc/init.d/rc3.d/
    ln -s /etc/init.d/hqagent.sh S99hqagent
    ln -s /etc/init.d/hqagent.sh K01hqagent
    cd ../rc5.d
    ln -s /etc/init.d/hqagent.sh S99hqagent
    ln -s /etc/init.d/hqagent.sh K01hqagent
    chkconfig --add hqagent.sh
    su - hqagent
    /opt/agent-5.8.1/bin/hq-agent.sh start
  fi
done < hosts.txt
```

error:

```
tar (child): agent-x86-64-linux-5.8.1.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
mv: cannot stat `/opt/agent.properties.nondmz': No such file or directory
mkdir: cannot create directory `/opt/hqagent/': File exists
ln: creating symbolic link `/opt/hqagent/agent-current': File exists
useradd: user 'hqagent' already exists
groupadd: group 'hqagent' already exists
chown: cannot access `/opt/agent-5.8.1/': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access `hqagent.sh': No such file or directory
error reading information on service hqagent.sh: No such file or directory
-bash: line 1: 10.145.34.6: command not found
-bash: line 2: 10.145.6.10: command not found
./hq-install.sh: line 29: /opt/agent-5.8.1/bin/hq-agent.sh: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Please post a *minimal* example, how you run the script and specify what you think is wrong with the result. Also, properly indent you code...this is really hard on the eye.

Comment: `Cannot open: No such file or directory` is evident. did you check whether files are in palce ?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the problem is that you run this script on the "master" server, but somehow expect the branches of your if-statement to be run on the remote hosts.  You need to factor those branches out into their own files, copy them to the remote hosts along with the other files, and in your if-statement, each branch should just be a ssh command to the remote host, triggering the script you copied over.

So your master script would look something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
export AGENT=agent-x86-64-linux-5.8.1.tar.gz
export AGENT_PROPERTIES_NONDMZ=agent.properties.nondmz
export agent_INIT=agent.sh

# Scripts containing the stuff you want done on the remote hosts
centos_setup=centos_setup.sh
other_setup=other_setup.sh

echo "####Installing hqagent####"

while read host; do
  echo "  ++ Copying files to $host"
  scp $AGENT $AGENT_PROPERTIES_NONDMZ $agent_INIT root@$host:/opt

  echo -n "  ++ Running remote part on $host "
  if ssh -n root@$host '[ "$(awk "/CentOS/{print}" /etc/*release)" ] '
  then
    echo "(centos)"
    scp $centos_setup root@$host:/opt
    ssh root@host "/opt/$centos_setup"
  else
    echo "(generic)"
    scp $other_setup root@$host:/opt
    ssh root@host "/opt/$other_setup"
  fi
done < hosts.txt
```

The contents of the two auxiliary scrips would be the current contents of the if-branches in your original.